# Permissions in GraphQL

Tags: permissions, graphql

How to manage permissions in GraphQL?

For example if someone makes query to retrieve posts, and user doesn't have permissions, what should be response in such case?

How should be response when no permissions for subcollection? For example posts+comments, when user have permissions for posts but not for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, whenever the user doesn't have permission to view the object, you either return null or you return an error. It's really up to you and your requirements. Same for sub-collections.

I know this isn't a very satisfying answer, and I'm sorry. But your question is too broad and there are far too many possible answers, and they all depend on your requirements.

I recommend watching this GraphQL Summit 2017 video "[Ryan Chenkie - Handling Authentication and Authorization in GraphQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_Bcw7BULC8). It outlines a couple viable approaches with sample code.

Also, here's a recent answer that looks pretty useful
[Graphql @include with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959096/graphql-include-with-expression)